# How to set group.id in KSQL application

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I need to set a 'group.id' property in my KSQL application.

I know that is possible in Kafka Stream application by 'application.id' property, but it dosn't work for KSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `ksql.service.id`. Ref: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/faq.html#how-do-i-add-ksql-servers-to-an-existing-ksql-cluster

Comment: From documentation, I found "If multiple KSQL servers connect to the same Kafka cluster (i.e. the same bootstrap.servers) and have the same ksql.service.id they will form a KSQL cluster and share the workload", but I need to set up consumer group ID for the single KSQL continuous query.

Comment: The use case is: 1) start the query 2) terminate and drop query 3) re-start the same query (i need to re-start from last committed offset, not from earliest/latest)

Comment: That's not currently possible with KSQL

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Is this feature on KSQL's roadmap? Restoring the query from the last committed offset seems a rather common use case.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt is that  use case possible now with ksql?

Comment: updated link https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/ksqldb/faq.html#how-do-i-add-ksqldb-servers-to-an-existing-ksqldb-cluster